# External Panel in JQuery Mobile is losing its CSS style

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Using JQuery Mobile 1.4.5, it appears that my external panel cannot hold a style!

Conventional wisdom states that `.enhanceWithin();` should be called to update the contents of an element, but this does not appear to give good results with the current version of JQM.

[Fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/9desxsj9/2/).

Has this been updated? Every answer I have found on the topic of dynamic elements losing their style is using an older version of JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default jQM 1.4.x only has 'A' and 'B' themes. You have set theme to 'C' which does not exist unless you add it to the CSS.  For the fiddle, change it to:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="menuPanel" data-theme="b">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
    <li><a href="#featured">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#featured">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9desxsj9/3/)**